# Single Quote not getting replaced with Blank in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have an expression and I am trying to replace all single quote with blank but when I try to save my controller.js it gives error:

> Error: 0Adf4000000en6S: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Unterminated string [96, 41]: '/g, "");

I am trying this code:

```
var sqlExpression = 'gattexlead_flag'_1;
var text1 = sqlExpression.replace(/'/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bug with the lexer. You will probably need to escape it:

```
var text1 = sqlExpression.replace(/\'/g, "");
```

---

For now, if you need a regular expression that fails to compile, compile it ahead of time:

```
var regex = new RegExp("'","g");
var text1 = sqlExpression.replace(regex, "");
```

Comment: No bueno - still fails with v42.

Comment: @dzh Yeah, I just tested that (again). I came up with a viable alternative that does compile, though.

Comment: @sfdcfox Can you share what your "viable alternative" was?

Comment: @zachelrath The last edit: `var regex = new RegExp("'","g");`

Comment: any alternatives?