# Not able to replace DoubleQuote from a specific Javascript String in Aura Helper component using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, aura, regular-expressions, helper

I want to replace DoubleQuote from a specific JavaScript String in Aura Helper component using Regular Expression.

My JS String is `ab ","{ cd`

I want it to be `ab ,{ cd`

I am performing this operation:

```
var data = "ab \",\"{ cd";
data = data.replace(/\",\"{/g, ",{"); // Getting error at this line
```

But, every time I am receiving a Salesforce error message, while performing the 2nd line

> **org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException:
>   Unterminated string [300, 46]: ');': Source**

Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the string you are manipulating is a JSON in the string representation and after you have done the manipulation, it is no longer a valid JSON.

Comment: @manjit5190 Yes. Probably you are correct..

Answer (score 0):

Following works fine for me

```
var data = "ab \",\"{ cd";
var ex=new RegExp("\"","g");
console.log(data.replace(ex,""));
```

also [Single Quote not getting replaced with Blank in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205458/single-quote-not-getting-replaced-with-blank-in-lightning)