# In my aura component CSV export, double quotes break the export

Tags: lightning-aura-components, csv

I have an aura component that exports a list of cases to a CSV. In the description field, customers have been inserting double quotes in the field (example "variable") which breaks the columns of the CSV export.

When I try to add a replace in the component controller like this

```
row['Description'] = row['Description'].replace(/",/g,'""');
```

or like this

```
row['Description'] = row['Description'].replace(/"/g, '\"');
```

The framework throws this error 'Unterminated string [311, 103]: '');'

Can I escape a doublequote so my CSV exports properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with Aura's parser, it [sometimes gets things wrong](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/205458/2984). I would have presumed this would have been fixed by now, but apparently it's still an issue? The general workaround is to use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instead:

```
var doubleQuoteRegExp = new RegExp('"','g'); // g = global flag, equal to /"/g;
row['Description'] = row['Description'].replace(doubleQuoteRegExp, '""');
```

Comment: That was it! It totally fixed my CSV export. Thank you so much! If this were Reddit sfdcfox, I'd give you gold!

Comment: @afandre It's okay. Here you can give me a ✔ if you want (and also to let people know this answer was accepted).